# Will the MSI R7770 work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati

I'm doing my first build and have Ubuntu 12.04 successfully up and running. I've been reading a lot that there are issues trying to use a graphics card, specifically AMD. How do I go about installing this graphics card? Should it just be a plug and play ordeal? Do I need to upgrade to 12.10? Do I need to download some drivers?

Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks. I'm a complete noob with Linux, long time windows and osx user. Are you saying to upgrade to 12.10 and it will be better supported? Where can i download Catalyst? Thanks for the help. And what would you do in my situation?

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience with the same GPU (HD 7770) the Radeon driver doesn't provide what you'd call good support especially in the kernel version of Ubuntu 12.04, for that I used Catalyst which you can install as explained here:

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)

If you don't want to use Catalyst for whatever reason, you can upgrade your kernel which will include better suport for newer cards from the Radeon driver, you can update it as explained here:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/142000#142000)

Comment: Thanks Uri. This is exactly what I was looking for. Very clear. Again, Thank you!